# Why is my question on hold?

Tags: support, closing

First things first, this is the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265323/did-beta-last-more) I'm talking about.

After reading it, it's easy to realize that, as I said on a comment,

> I just wanted to know, it won't help future generations understand the past, but I was just curious...

But in my opinion, is just as valid as another "simple" question. I didn't have a problem (unless curiosity is a problem), I just didn't know the answer to my question, so I came here looking for someone able to shed some light on it.

I cannot actually see the bad side of it, even less when more people was asking the same in-game.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/should-there-be-some-way-to-designate-answers-as-deprecated

Comment: It is clear that a beta version will no longer appear when the game is launched. I'd understand if it was a question related to a specific version of the game but how would I specify that it is in beta version more than saying the word "beta"?

Comment: Not because of the comments, I was talking about the downvotes, sorry if missunderstood.

Comment: Again, most likely not personal, but aimed towards the question itself. As you can see for the comments and close-votes, people don't think highly of the question. Naturaly this is reflected on the votes.

Answer (score 6):

This question was closed because it is "too localized". The actual close reason for "too localized" has been removed, but the concept still applies and questions that fit into that idea are close-worthy. Unfortunately, there's no great close reason for that (it was removed because these types of questions are fairly rare), so we have to make do with another.

"Too localized" means that a question only applies to a very, *very* small subset of people, and it's not broadly applicable to the Internet at large. In this case, this question has zero ongoing value because the beta is over, and will never exist again in the same form, and whether it extended a few hours past its intended deadline or not will never matter to anyone in the future.

Comment: So, is everyone here suppossed to only make questions relevant to future generations and worldwide? I guess those are quite big standards.. If a question made by someone just because he was curious is a bad question, rules should be changed.

Comment: @Alex When you look at a question, think, "Will this question be relevant to anyone else, ever again?" If the answer is "no", or even "probably not", then the question probably doesn't belong here. Maybe on a forum, or on reddit, but not here.

Comment: Does this site work different that SO or SF?

Comment: @Alex Every site has its own unique rules, but that rule is the same across the whole network. Whether a site is lax or strict in enforcing it may be different, but in theory "too localized" content is off topic everywhere.

Comment: I've been asking, answering and seeing very specific questions on SO and SF for a long time now... only general questions become part of the `FAQ`, others get answered or not, but never closed.

Comment: @Alex It's not about specificity. It's about future audience. A question about a specific problem that someone else *may* run into in the future is fine. A question about what color car is in the parking lot outside is not, even if it would be otherwise on topic for whatever site it's on. That's the distinction. The latter question is objective, but it's not *useful* to *anyone*. It's too localized. Much like asking if some service that went offline was online for an extra couple hours once.

Comment: Related: [Can we stop closing questions that have become obsolete as “Too Localized”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5282/4797)

Comment: To clarify, it was closed because a single person (a moderator) thought it was the correct action. At present, there are 4 votes to reopen the question.

Comment: @Timelord64 It's closed because it's *off topic*. Raven closed it, I defended it without even consulting him. It went through the reopen queue and the consensus was to leave it closed, and at least 2 of the reopen votes are from people who consistently claim mods are oppressive when we literally *gain nothing by being so*. Ok.

Comment: @StrixVaria, it didn't 'go through' the review queue, it is **going** through the review queue (literally just came up, then). It is not your place, as a moderator, to disqualify votes based off your past experience with the users that cast them. This is obviously a controversial topic, but the only evidence I see of it actually being discussed is a meta post that says 'stop closing questions for this reason' and a mod that says 'make note of the localisation, but do not close them'.

Comment: To say your trying to be oppressive is a bit of the top, but I can certainly see how your actions in this case might have given some that interpretation.

Comment: @Timelord64 My actions of literally not even casting a vote? Moderators are *community-elected* and are given the ability to perform actions not so that they can just sit on their hands and do nothing. Moderators, at least on Arqade, are always acting in what they feel is in *the best interest of the site*. If you believe that we are oppressive, I believe you are delusional.

Comment: Take a breather, and read through the comment again. I do not think your being oppressive. I think others could see it that way, which you confirm to be your impression on at least two other users.

Comment: And once again, try and address the fact that this has already been discussed, and there are users still voting to open this question. I am seeing a distinct lack of that, and I would personally expect more from a moderator.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen some comments in the original question that suggest the question can only be answered by a developer.  This would make the question off-topic for the [developer intent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) reason:

> Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative

There is a good argument for this question being "developer intent".  The underlying reason for the rule is to stop questions that can only be answered by a developer.  In this case, it has been assumed only the developer can say why the beta was closed later than advertised.

However, I would like to make some points that would suggest we, as gamers, can provide some expertise as to why the beta closed later than the time you provided:

- Timezone differences (as already mentioned in the comments for the original question)
- The development team being unable to close active servers (does anyone remember the [Halo 2 server closure on the original Xbox](http://kotaku.com/5535672/the-last-man-to-play-halo-2-on-xbox-live)?)

Yes, sure, identifying possible problems is speculative, but there are plenty of examples in the past where some game doesn't ship on time, or some server doesn't close at the exact posted time.

You'll probably find there won't be a great appetite for getting this question re-opened because at best it is borderline speculative, and already obsolete.  If someone provided a good and/or correct answer right now, how would this help you?

Comment: It's all about curiosity, I said it already twice, I don't have any problems with it, I enjoyed playing even more, but I was just curious about it, nothing more, isn't curiosity a valid reason to ask questions here?

Comment: @Alex - curiosity is one reason for asking a question.